# Why am I getting command not found even though path to command exists in PATH variable?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

On Mac OSX 10.10.1
I get command not found for anything installed in /usr/local/bin (however command is found if I use sudo)
PATH variable contains this path.
for example pip. Here are some lines from terminal:

---

```
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$ echo $PATH/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$ ls /usr/local/bin  
2to3            idle3.4         pydoc3          python3.4-32        rtmpdump        tclsh8.5        wish8.5
2to3-3.4        pip         pydoc3.4        python3.4-config    rtmpgw          tclsh8.6        wish8.6
easy_install        pip2            python3         python3.4m      rtmpsrv         tclvfse         youtube-dl
easy_install-2.7    pip2.7          python3-32      python3.4m-config   rtmpsuck        teacup
easy_install-3.4    pip3            python3-config      pyvenv          tclselect       udemy-dl
idle3           pip3.4          python3.4       pyvenv-3.4      tclsh           wish
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$ which pip
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$ sudo which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
Dylans-MacBook-Air:edX Dylan$
```

---

What could be causing this behaviour and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the permissions for `/usr/local/bin/pip` ? Maybe execution is only allowed to root.

Comment: Can you run other commands in `/usr/local/bin`? Is `pip` a symlink? Could you add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip`?

Answer (score 3):

The fix I ended up was removing all home brew Python and fixing up the system Python.

```
brew remove python
brew remove python3
brew cleanup
```

Check for the system pip and python (or absence of pip is OK too).

```
which python
which pip
which pip3
which python3
```

At this point, you need to `easy_install` a system based pip:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
pip --version
```

You should now have a pip that's based on /Library/Python (and pip 7.1.2 against python 2.7 for El Capitan in October 2015)

```
mac:~ me$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
mac:~ me$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
mac:~ me$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```